# Нахождение закономерности чисел

Tags: числа

У меня есть провайдер, он продает карточки пополнения. Они состоят из номера и кода. Как я понимаю, используются два простых числа.

Вопрос: как подобрать данные простые числа? Есть ли алгоритм? Программа? Сервис?

Например:

1. Номер P0647832, код 0039 3558 1281 8809.
2. Номер P0647833, код 8945 0246 7287 9945.

Comment: @mkrichet1, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

А отвечать вам будет законно? Меня не посадят за соучастие? ))

А вы уверены, что используются простые числа? Последнее число делится на 5. Если же использовать простое - чем плохи 3/5/7/11?

Если же имелось ввиду "взаимнопростые", то N и N+1 - разве не взаимнопростые?

Чувство у меня такое, что используются совсем другие алгоритмы, возможен даже вариант:

```
N = N + 1
CODE = random()
store(N, CODE)
```

Либо используются RSA ключи, каждый номер шифруется, а полученное значение становится кодом. Т.е., проверяя расшифровку и код, можно определить валидность карточки

Answer (score 4):

Вероятно, используется схема «с солью»: у провайдера есть суперсекретный пароль, а код карточки считется как хэш-ф-я от (её_номера + пароль).

Вариантов самой ф-ии много, но главное требование к ней такое, что обратное восстановление невозможно. Как и предсказание следующего кода.

А ещё провайдер хранит у себя в БД все номера карточек, а, может, также и их кодов, и «вычёркивает» использованные.

Заработайте уже денег и оплатите интернет : )

Comment: халява это бич всех славян )